# Is it possible to 'talk' to servers in a Windows intranet and pull information? (.Net 4.0)

Tags: .net, .net-4.0, windows-server

I am attempting to make a program that will pull data such as OS, IP, Server Name, Websites, Databases, etc. in a server farm.  Is there a .Net library that allows you to connect to servers and get information such as this with the proper authentication?   I do not really know where to start, thank you.

Most of the servers are 2003 standard/enterprise both x86 and x64.

Comment: I guess using SNMP, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Network_Management_Protocol, will get you some information like what OS is used. It is used to let computers (normally in the local network) get information about each other.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it's called [WMI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394582(VS.85).aspx) (Windows management and instrumentation). Here is a link to use [WMI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms257340(VS.80).aspx) in .net.

Comment: +1 Good answer. Found this SO question if OP is going to use this with Mono; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1003355/the-mono-net-framework-and-wmi

Answer (score 2):

Won't you need to know the server name or IP address before hand to connect to the server to get the rest of the info?