# Performance Counter API in Mono

Tags: c#, performance, mono, counter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [The Mono .NET framework and WMI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1003355/the-mono-net-framework-and-wmi)

Hi guys I'm using WMI to get system information in windows platform but I really need to do this also on linux environment like Ubuntu and Red Hat using Mono. Is there any api that is available for me to get resource information?

I need to get all resource information ( cpu % , memory et.al )of Red Hat or Ubuntu using mono. Is there any way I can do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1003355/the-mono-net-framework-and-wmi seem to cover this question

Comment: What's wrong with this stuff http://www.mono-project.com/Mono_Performance_Counters ?