# How can I get the partition UUID of a disk in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, mono, filesystems, uuid

I need to be able to get the partition/filesystem UUID of a partition, similar to how you can with `VOL` in WinDOS and `ls -l /dev/disks/by-partuuid` in *nix, but with C# code. What's the best way to do this?

For reference, I need to be able to get the UUID from either the current directory, or the "closest" mount upwards.

**EDIT:** My bad, should've said this up front: it needs to run on Mono.

Comment: Then I guess WMI is out of the question...

Comment: System.Management exists, if that's what you're referencing.

Comment: @tikking1 I was searching in `WMI` (Windows Management Instrumentation) till you updated the post it should be supported by mono. I doubt `WMI` is supported on Linux/Mac. So the `System.Management` namespace might be there, I doubt it supports the `WMI` queries: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1003355/the-mono-net-framework-and-wmi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write the code for both platforms and then decide at runtime based on `Environment.OSVersion.Platform` which one to use. Make sure you write the implementations in separate methods (or classes), that way the runtime won't attempt to load the pinvoked libraries for the wrong platform.

For windows you can use the GetVolumeInformation or the WMI as described in the other answer. For linux you can use the directory you mentioned in your question possibly in conjunction with pinvoking readlink or using the Mono.Posix assembly.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to P/Invoke [GetVolumeInformation](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32.getvolumeinformation) function.

Comment: Does this work on Mono? If so, how? (I couldn't find Kernel32.dll in the References/Packages section)

Comment: No, P/Invoke only works on windows platform. Sorry, I didn't know your question is targeted to mono.

Comment: My bad for not specifying.

Comment: You can try execute shell and get result from the shell. http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=320322

Comment: That's what I was dreading. If there are no other answers when I wake up, I'll accept this.